# using nextLine() and nextToken methods in files

Tags: java, string, file, token

Hi I'm developing a simple student register application that asks the user for student info and saves it in a file. The app is intended for consulting, deleting, and modifying information as well. The information provided consists of an enrollment number which is unique for every student, the name of the student and their degree. All this information is saved in an object and written in a line of the file. I'm having some trouble in the method that asks for the info. Let's say I've got an student whose info is "33333 John Stevens Medicine" When I provide the enrollment number, the app returns the info for the nextLine in the file. Source code below:

```
String matricula= matriculafield.getText();
    Scanner fileIn;
    StringTokenizer st;
    try{
        fileIn = new Scanner(new FileReader("estudiantes.txt"));
        while(fileIn.hasNextLine())
        {
            st= new StringTokenizer(fileIn.nextLine());
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                if(st.nextToken().equals(matricula))
                {
                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,fileIn.nextLine());
                }
            }


        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No se encontró al alumno");
    }
```

matricula is the enrollment number, then I divide the String in tokens and if any token matches the matricula variable I should get the line where that token is but it returns the next line of the file instead.

Whats wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: *What is wrong?* You call `nextLine()` again, thereby showing the next line. Every call to `nextLine()` returns a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
st= new StringTokenizer(fileIn.nextLine());
```

To:

```
String currentLine = fileIn.nextLine();
st= new StringTokenizer(currentLine);
```

Then change:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,fileIn.nextLine());
```

To:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,currentLine);
```